# .load() does not work in browsers

Tags: html, jquery, load

I use Coda 2 which has a built-in browser. Here's a code:

```
$('#mtbLink').click(function() {
    $("#loadHere").load("file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/another/test.html #loadThis")
});
```

It works in Coda browser, but doesn't work in Safari, Mozilla and Yandex.Browser (chromium-based browser). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make AJAX requests to the local file system. To test this in FF/Chrome etc. you need to place your `test.html` file on an accessible webserver.